# Confirmation email not sent FOSUserBundle Symfony

Tags: email, symfony

I just installed the FOSUserbundle and I want to have the e-mail confirmation enabled. Meaning if someone registers the user should get an email with an activation link.

Here is the config.yml file:

```
fos_user:
db_driver:     orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: Project\UserBundle\Entity\User
service:
    mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
group:
    group_class: Project\UserBundle\Entity\Group
profile:
    form:
        type: project_user_profile
registration:
    form:
        type: project_user_registration
    confirmation:
        enabled: true
        #template: FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
        from_email:
            address:     zairi.ibrahim@gmail.com
            sender_name: Simlinx User Registration
```

And

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
transport: %mailer_transport%
encryption: %mailer_encryption%
host:      %mailer_host%
username:  %mailer_user%
password:  %mailer_password%
spool:     { type: memory }
```

And parameters.yml :

```
mailer_transport:  gmail
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_host:       ~
mailer_user:       zairi.ibrahim
mailer_password:   xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It works in the first time, but now it does not work anymore !!

Thnks

Comment: You find a solution my friend?

Answer (score 0):

I have this configuration and works for me. If your configuration works in the first time, it is possible **Gmail** block your account to send mails with symfony.

config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    encryption:%mailer_encryption%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    auth_mode: %mailer_auth_mode% login
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

And parameters.yml:

```
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_host:       smtp.gmail.com
mailer_auth_mode:  login
mailer_user:       zairi.ibrahim@gmail.com
mailer_password:   xxxxxxxxxxxx
```